# Is it legal to bypass Keurig coffee maker DRM?

Tags: united-states, copyright, drm

Keurig coffee makers have DRM so only approved pods will work. Is it legal to circumvent this DRM and use "unauthorized" pods?

Comment: Lexmark tried this with ink cartridges and lost. Do you violate Keurigs copyright?

Comment: @gnasher729 no, there's nothing copyrightable involved.

Comment: That was Lexmark’s problem. They didn’t read the DMCA law, they only read “DRM … circumvention … illegal … yadayadayada”. They tried to get copyright in. Their printers (roughly) only accepted ink cartridges that said “I am an original Lexmark printer cartridge”. So all the cloned cartridges said that, which was deemed not copyright violation, because the text had to be necessarily exactly that text.

Comment: Does DRM = Digital Rights Management?  A container of coffee grounds is not "digital" anything...

Comment: @MichaelHall no, but I don't think my phone manufacturer has a "right" to not have their products rooted, but without a DMCA exemption from the LoC, they could sue. And CSS (Content Scramble System, not Cascading Style Sheets) can be easily bypassed and doesn't really "manage" anything. If the R and the M aren't required for something to be DRM, why should I expect the D to be required? 

Comment: I thought you were asking about a coffee maker, not a phone…

Comment: P.S.  what happened to your question about someone stealing a car they stood to inherit?  I had a better answer I wanted to post but can’t find it.

Comment: @MichaelHall the question is about coffee makers; those were just examples of why I thought this could still be DRM, even though coffee isn't digital. In the case of rooting a phone, the DMCA does not protect an existing right of the manufacturer, it gives them the ability to sue (or at least, would if the LoC didn't make an exemption). DVD CSS DRM doesn't effectively "manage" copyrights, because it can by bypassed so easily. If DRM doesn't have to protect a right, and it doesn't have to effectively manage anything, I wasn't sure if anything digital had to be involved.

Comment: @MichaelHall https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/81932/is-it-legal-to-take-something-you-didnt-know-was-yours

Comment: I don’t know what “rooting” a phone has to do with your question then.  If the instructions said to wash using Dove dish soap and you use Palmolive, is that legal?  Why or why not?  It’s your coffee maker, do whatever you want with it, they have no say once it’s sold.  It is your possession!  Worst you can do is void the warranty.  Phones may be different when there’s a service contract in play.

Comment: @MichaelHall rooting my phone does not actually violate anyone's copyrights, but it would be illegal under the DMCA's DRM clause if the LoC hadn't made an exception. It seems obvious that you should be able to do what you want with your coffee maker, but it seems equally obvious that you should be able to do what you want with your phone, but you can't without a special exemption.

Comment: I don't know even what rooting is or how it applies here, but if you want to ask a question about your phone then ask a question about your phone.  Phones transmit signals, they are subject to reasonable regulations based on that fact. Coffee makers aren't in the same league as devices connected to a network so stop trying to compare them!  (If you want to use your phone to shim a leg of your coffee table to reduce the wobble as you enjoy your cup of Keurig coffee made with a refilled black market pod, then have at it...)

Comment: @MichaelHall rooting a phone doesn't usually affect the modem at all. You can legally buy a phone (PinePhone) that gives you full root access (and the ability to replace the OS) out of the box by design, and also the technical ability to *rewrite the DSP firmware*, so the FCC does not rely on people not rooting their phones.

Comment: Again, this question is about a coffee maker...

Comment: Someone, it doesn’t matter whether a protection can be circumvented “easily”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR: Yes, it's legal.

1. There is no patent nor copyright infringement when consumers use third party coffee pods or modify their appliance to accept those pods.
2. There may be antitrust infringement when companies take steps to block consumers from using third party consumables like coffee pods.

---

It's not just legal, Keurig [paid $31 million to settle a lawsuit](https://news.bloomberglaw.com/product-liability-and-toxics-law/keurig-settles-consumers-k-cup-antitrust-claims-for-31-million) over claims their attempts to block people from using third-party pods violated antitrust law.

The Supreme Court confirmed consumers' right to use a product however they like once it has been purchased in a very related [2016 case about printer cartridges](https://slate.com/technology/2017/05/the-supreme-court-says-third-parties-can-sell-printer-cartridge-ink.html):

> The Supreme Court decided 7-1 in favor of Impression on both counts, ruling that once a company has sold a product, it can’t dictate how the product is used—meaning that consumers have free rein to refurbish, repair, or resell items they’ve lawfully bought. “The purchaser and all subsequent owners are free to use or resell the product just like any other item of personal property, without fear of an infringement lawsuit,” Chief Justice John Roberts wrote for the majority opinion.

Answer (score 1):

According to Fortinet.com Cybergolssary:

> Digital rights management (DRM) is the use of technology to control and manage access to **copyrighted material**. Another DRM meaning is taking control of **digital content** away from the person who possesses it and handing it to a computer program.

As you acknowledge in your first comment, there is nothing copyrightable about a coffee pod.  Nor is it digital content, therefore DRM is irrelevant.

Kuerig, as well as other companies, market a product that uses proprietary consumable components of a form that only their product will work with.  However, there is nothing illegal about you circumventing their attempt to sell you more of their coffee.  It is your coffee maker, do with it as you please...

Comment: If keurig prints a poem on their pods, that would be copyrightable so other pod makers better not print that poem. Except if the coffee machine has a scanner that checks for this poem and refuses to use pods without it, then the poem suddenly becomes functional and loses copyright protection.

Comment: @gnasher729, I hope you are kidding…

Comment: yes, the whole idea is ridiculous, but Keurig makes a lot of money from these pods and will try to keep that money to themselves. The failed "copyright" hack is exactly what Lexmark tried with printers. It failed because some text that could have been copyrighted was _required_ to make other manufacturer's printer cartridges print, and because it was _required_ to make this cartridges print, copying that text became legal.